# initiate class with an argument in class declaration

Tags: c++, class, constructor

in my object State, i'd like to have object pq. but pq needs to be initialized with a parameter. is there a way to include a class that depends on a parameter into another class?

file.h

> ```
> class Pq
> {
>   int a;
>   Pq(ClassB b);
> };
> class State
> {
>   ClassB b2;
>   Pq pq(b2);
>   State(ClassB b3);
> };
> ```

file.cc

> `State::State(ClassB b3) : b2(b3) {}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can initialize it in the *initializer list*, just like you do with `b2`:

```
State::State(ClassB b3) : b2(b3), pq(b2) {}
```

Keep in mind that members are initialized in the order they are *declared* in the header file, not the order of the initializers in the initializer list.

You need to remove the attempt at initialize it in the header as well:

```
class Pq
{
  int a;
  Pq(ClassB b);
};
class State
{
  ClassB b2;
  Pq pq;
  State(ClassB b3);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Class State{
public:
       State(ClassB& bref):b2(bref),pq(b2){} // Depends on the order you declare objects
                                             // in private/public/protected

private:
    ClassB b2;
    Pq pq;

};
```

In the above code you have to maintain that order in the initialization list otherwise you will get what not expected..therefore quite risky